# Fix code socket io and knockout

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, socket.io

I get data from Mongodb  by Socket and send to client, 
I use knockout to binding , but error can not apply bindings multiple times .
Can you help me fix code

Code:

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  function getdata() {
    var stock = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      stock.push(data[i]);

    }
    return stock;
  }

  var results = getdata();
  var ViewModel = {
    stocks: ko.observableArray(results)
  };

  $(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, $("#stock").get(0));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate *creating* and *updating* your view model.

You haven't quite provided a real repro, but in your context it would go along these lines:

```
var ViewModel = {
  stocks: ko.observableArray([])
};

$(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, $("#stock").get(0));
});

socket.on('data', function(data) {
  function getdata() {
    var stock = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      stock.push(data[i]);

    }
    return stock;
  }

  var results = getdata();

  ViewModel.stocks(results);
});
```

Calling `stocks` as a function with 1 argument is *setting* its value. You could also push one or more items to the view model property if you want to update it. Check [the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) for info on all observable array methods.

---

PS. Most likely, you can simplify to something like this:

```
var ViewModel = {
  stocks: ko.observableArray([])
};

$(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, $("#stock").get(0));
});

socket.on('data', function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      ViewModel.stocks.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
});
```